# Laravel Eloquent Relationship get one column from other table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, relation

I have question about Laravel Eloquent.

I have following tables

```
Users
    -id
    -email

Money
    -id
    -user_id
    -amount
    -total
```

User has many Money

I want to use something like $user->current_money
then i want to get the total from the last Money

i need this because i want to show all user's current money in table

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->current_money}}</td>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

is there good practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use appends in Laravel Eloquent in order to achieve this.

in your Users model get add the $appends array. like this

```
protected $appends = ['current_money'];
```

this will look for a method `getCurrentMoneyAttribute()` in the User model. it should look like this.

```
public function getCurrentMoneyAttribute()
{

    return 0.00;

}
```

with the implication of the you have implanted the relationship between User and Money tables. your method should look like this,

```
public function getCurrentMoneyAttribute()
{

    return $this->money()->latest()->first()->total;

}
```

and when when ever you call the `$user->current_money` laravel execute the query and it will get the last row of the Money that is relevant to that user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent Relationships as you are asking about and a single query to accomplish this. Using append is a slippery slope because now it will add it to all user queries and may cause bloat as the app grows. As well appending it will have 2 queries versus a single one.

In the user model you define the relationship like so:

```
/**
 * Get money for a user
 */
public function money()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Money', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Then you can query the user like this in a single query for performance:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->with(['money'])->first();
```

or

```
$user = User::with('money')->findOrFail($id);
```

or now you can eager load the money as well since the relationship is now defined in the user model.

```
$user = Auth::user(); // or however you are pulling the user from the DB.
$user->money;
```

Then loop through the different money's.

Comment: A user has many money, and he wants to get the latest total of the money for the user. I think your relationship `belongsTo` is not correct

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: You have edit hasmany relation its okay, but now you can't access `$user->money->total;` because it's an array.